# Invalid argument in Visualization Manager crashes Visual Studio

Tags: visualization, twincat

I have two visualizations which I switch using buttons on a third one.
It works flawlessly, but every time I try to open my Visualization Manager, it shows an error and VS crashes some seconds after it.

[image: Error message]

I looked where it could came from but I can't find anything related to.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I have no idea where to start. There are no errors in compilation and project works in a real environment. (CX)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is this your first project with visualisations? If so, then it could mean there is a bug with TC, I would reinstall it.

Comment: Hi! Thx for your answer. Reinstallation didn't work, but version upgrade did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version update did the trick from 4024.40 to 4024.47.